# Router D-Link 600 B1 EDB-ID-15666 Vulnerability

Tags: network, vulnerability, router

I would like to ask how to update my router firmware at D-Link 600 B1. The problem is I download the newest firmware update in .bin file and when I plug in to my router and try to update this firmware, the router says that this file is not recognisible so I can't update firmware.

My router was hacked by some hackers. I know this because Avast after scan detected EDB-ID-15666 Vulnerability hole, and my network statistics showed some huge traffic despite I wasn't doing anything on PC.

I post here screenshot from this scan:

[image]

Is total reset to production setup a only way to fix that ?

Thanks in advance for help :-).

Comment: This would be a question for D-Link - it's entirely possible that the only way to fix it is a factory reset, or even that it's not possible to fix, in the event that the factory reset process has been corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

The router may still be communicating with the hacker's computer, and thwarting your attempts to repair it.  Try bypassing the malware by downloading the router's update file from a different network, such as a coffee shop, and save it. When you get home, disconnect your D-link from the internet, do a 'factory reset', reboot it, and then try uploading the new image to it.